# "no suitable method found" when using hasItem Hamcrest Matcher

Tags: java, hamcrest

When I run the following jUnit test:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    List<Map<String,String>> data=new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
    map.put("x","y");
    data.add(map);

    assertThat(data, hasItem(hasKey("x")));
}
```

I get this:

```
Error:(239, 9) java: no suitable method found for assertThat(java.util.List>,org.hamcrest.Matcher>>)
    method org.junit.Assert.assertThat(java.lang.String,T,org.hamcrest.Matcher) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.junit.Assert.assertThat(T,org.hamcrest.Matcher) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        inferred: java.util.List>
        upper bound(s): java.lang.Iterable>,java.lang.Object)
```

It looks like something in the generics is breaking down.  What is it?

Comment: only 3 upvotes for a question, about tests, that _every_ Android programmer should ask? I am ashamed of this industry! Everyone teach more testing!

Answer (score 3):

`javac` doesn't know how to infer the generic type for some of those methods.

`assertThat` expects a value and a `Matcher` of that type. You'll have to be explicit

```
Assert.assertThat(data, Matchers.<Map<String, String>> hasItem(Matchers.hasKey("x")));
```

Though this should work without the explicit type argument in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I think they updated the function's signature. I found that I was using an old syntax.

old `assertThat(singleParam)`

```
assertThat(res.getStatus()).isEqualTo(200);
```

new `assertThat(actual, expected)`

```
assertThat(res.getEntity(), is("Testing"));
```